# Protobuf strange behaviour with enums

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I have the following protobuf definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
message ACL {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  enum Foo {
    BAR = 0;
    BAZ = 1;
  }
  enum Corpus {
    UNIVERSAL = 0;
    WEB = 1;
  }
  Foo foo = 1;
  Corpus corpus = 2;
}
```

When I use in Python, it will store/show the corpus field but not the foo field:

```
>>> import acl_pb2
>>> p = acl_pb2.ACL(foo="BAR", corpus="WEB")
>>> p
corpus: WEB
```

Comment: could you include the generated file, im curious

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kRHN6xhw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In proto3, zeros are defaults and defaults are zeros. Defaults (zeros) are not transmitted, thus: there is no actual data sent for `foo = "Bar"`, since that is a zero. However, your model should be able to discover that `foo` exists and *has* the implicit value of `Bar`/`0`. If it doesn't, that sounds like a curiosity of the python code-gen.

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to figure out why the code at the other is not picking up the default (0)

Comment: @anteatersa as a tip: it can be useful to reserve the first enum position (which must have value zero) for an "unknown/none" entry